# systemd: Failed to parse calendar specification, ignoring

Tags: systemd, systemd-timer

I am trying to clean my docker registry daily using systemd:

Here is myfile contents:

```
[Unit]
Description=registry-gc

[Timer]
OnCalendar=41 15 * * *
Persistent=true

[Install]
WantedBy=timers.target
```

I get following error when runnig: sudo systemctl status registry-gc.timer

```
● registry-gc.timer - registry-gc
     Loaded: bad-setting (Reason: Unit registry-gc.timer has a bad unit file setting.)
     Active: inactive (dead)
    Trigger: n/a
   Triggers: ● registry-gc.service

/etc/systemd/system/registry-gc.timer:5: Failed to parse calendar specification, ignoring: 41 15 * * *
registry-gc.timer: Timer unit lacks value setting. Refusing.
```

also when I aks for :systemctl list-timers --all
I get:

```
NEXT                         LEFT           LAST                         PASSED       UNIT                         ACTIVATES
Fri 2022-09-02 16:34:04 CEST 42min left     Fri 2022-09-02 15:34:37 CEST 16min ago    anacron.timer                anacron.service
Fri 2022-09-02 22:37:19 CEST 6h left        Fri 2022-09-02 06:07:37 CEST 9h ago       fwupd-refresh.timer          fwupd-refresh.service
Sat 2022-09-03 00:00:00 CEST 8h left        Fri 2022-09-02 00:00:58 CEST 15h ago      logrotate.timer              logrotate.service
Sat 2022-09-03 00:00:00 CEST 8h left        Fri 2022-09-02 00:00:58 CEST 15h ago      man-db.timer                 man-db.service
Sat 2022-09-03 01:32:55 CEST 9h left        Fri 2022-09-02 12:47:34 CEST 3h 3min ago  apt-daily.timer              apt-daily.service
Sat 2022-09-03 06:40:33 CEST 14h left       Fri 2022-09-02 06:49:58 CEST 9h ago       apt-daily-upgrade.timer      apt-daily-upgrade.service
Sat 2022-09-03 08:48:51 CEST 16h left       Fri 2022-09-02 14:38:46 CEST 1h 12min ago motd-news.timer              motd-news.service
Sat 2022-09-03 12:09:58 CEST 20h left       Fri 2022-09-02 12:09:58 CEST 3h 41min ago systemd-tmpfiles-clean.timer systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service
Sun 2022-09-04 03:10:16 CEST 1 day 11h left Sun 2022-08-28 03:10:37 CEST 5 days ago   e2scrub_all.timer            e2scrub_all.service
Mon 2022-09-05 00:00:00 CEST 2 days left    Mon 2022-08-29 00:00:58 CEST 4 days ago   fstrim.timer                 fstrim.service
n/a                          n/a            n/a                          n/a          registry-gc.timer            registry-gc.service
```

I am using cron format for setting time. I want to run it daily at 15:41.
Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Check the docs for

- [systemd.timer](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.timer.html)
- [systemd.time](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.time.html)

You should use

```
OnCalendar=*-*-* 15:41:00
```

or simply

```
OnCalendar=15:41
```